# Put progressbar over the elements

Tags: android, progress-bar

The `Progressbar` is behind the elements like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r6tq.jpg), I would want to put over the elements.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@id/imgModoAuto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_height="446dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        tools:context=".fragment.LoginFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/relative">

        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: full code https://codeshare.io/5vQbRl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me before, try adding some `elevation` by adding   `android:elevation="10dp"` to the view.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: it worked! but idk but still is appearing some text behind the elements.

Comment: I would appreciate an upvote so others can also see this helpful.

Comment: for other elements, try adding elevation as well if that helps. but for the most part, check your view arrangement since you are using RelativeLayout